# model with this Email already exists in django

Tags: django

I have made a custom user model. signup and logout are working fine. but I have made a login form using that model. my model name is **usersignupmodel**. but whenever after signing-up, then I try to log in it gives me an error like that  `User signup model with this Email already exists.` I can not find the problem, please help.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager


class SignUpManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email,age,name, username, password=None):
        #if not email:
            #raise ValueError("insert user")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("insert username")
        if not name:
            raise ValueError("insert name")
        if not age:
            raise ValueError("insert age")
        user = self.model(
           email=self.normalize_email(email),
           username=username,
           age=age,
           name=name,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self,email,name,age,username, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            password=password,
            age=age,
            name=name,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True

        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class UserSignupModel(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60,unique=True)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="date joined", auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="last login", auto_now=True)

    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "username"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email','name','age']
    objects = SignUpManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
#migrate --run-syncdb in case no work
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from diabetes.models import UserSignupModel
from django.contrib.auth import login,authenticate,logout


class UserSignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    email=forms.EmailField(max_length=60,help_text="add a valid email address",required=True)
    name=forms.CharField(max_length=15,help_text="add a valid name")
    age=forms.CharField(max_length=15)

    class Meta:
        model=UserSignupModel
        fields=('email','name',"username",'age',"password1","password2")


class UserLoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password=forms.CharField(label="password",widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model=UserSignupModel
        fields=("email","password")

        def clean(self):
            if self.is_valid():

                email=self.cleaned_data['email']
                password=self.cleaned_data['password']

                if not authenticate(email=email,password=password):
                    raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid LOGIN")
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login,authenticate,logout
from diabetes.forms import UserSignupForm,UserLoginForm


def home(request):
    return render(request,'diabetes/home.html')

def signupuser(request):
    context={}
    if request.POST:
        form=UserSignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            email=form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            raw_password=form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            name=form.cleaned_data.get('name')
            age=form.cleaned_data.get('age')
            username=form.cleaned_data.get('username')
```

account=authenticate(email=email,password=raw_password,name=name,age=age,username=username)
                login(request,account)
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                context["reg_form"]=form

```
    else:
        form = UserSignupForm()
        context["reg_form"] = form
    return render (request,'diabetes/signupuser.html',context)


def logoutuser(request):

    logout(request)
    return redirect('home')

def loginuser(request):
    context={}

    user=request.user
    if user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')

    if request.method=="POST":
        form=UserLoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            password=request.POST["password"]
            email=request.POST["email"]
            user=authenticate(password=password,email=email)

            if user:
                login(request,user,)
                return redirect("home")

    else:
        form=UserLoginForm()


    context['form']=form
    return render(request,"diabetes/loginuser.html",context)
```

**loginuser.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        <p>

        {{ field.label_tag }}
        {{ field}}
        {% if field.help_text %}
             <small>{{ field.help_text }}</small>
        {% endif %}
        {% for field in form %}
         {% for error in field.errors %}
             <strong>{{ error }}</strong>
             {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% if form.non_field_errors %}
             <small>{{ form.non_field_errors}}</small>
        {% endif %}
        </p>
    {% endfor %}

    <input type="submit">SUBMIT</input>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As I suspected, the UserLoginForm was trying to make another registration, that is, create a new user again, instead of authenticate and do the login. That was happening because my form inherited from forms.ModelForm; changing from forms.ModelForm to forms.Form solved the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove following lines:

```py
form=UserLoginForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
```

You defined login and signup with same model, so `is_valid` should fail after signup. The form validates model to create a new instance, this is why you got this error.

Comment: Can you provide full traceback?

Comment: sorry i can not understand.

Comment: Can you add traceback to your question? Check the logs where you see `User signup model with this Email already exists` error message, copy and paste logs above the message