# my login form is not validating in django

Tags: django

i have made a custom user model. using that model i have made a login form, signup form. but sign up form and  logout works fine. but whenever i try to submit login form it does not authenticate. where is the problem? there is two authentication one is in for login in forms.py other is in views.py for login

forms.py

```
from django import forms

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from diabetes.models import UserSignupModel
from django.contrib.auth import login,authenticate,logout


class UserSignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    email=forms.EmailField(max_length=60,help_text="add a valid email address",required=True)
    name=forms.CharField(max_length=15,help_text="add a valid name")
    age=forms.CharField(max_length=15)

    class Meta:
        model=UserSignupModel
        fields=('email','name',"username",'age',"password1","password2")



class UserLoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password=forms.CharField(label="password",widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model=UserSignupModel
        fields=("email","password")

    def clean(self):
        if self.is_valid():

            email=self.cleaned_data['email']
            password=self.cleaned_data['password']

            if not authenticate(email=email,password=password,backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'):
                raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid LOGIN")
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager



class SignUpManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email,age,name, username, password=None):
        #if not email:
            #raise ValueError("insert user")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("insert username")
        if not name:
            raise ValueError("insert name")
        if not age:
            raise ValueError("insert age")
        user = self.model(
           email=self.normalize_email(email),
           username=username,
           age=age,
           name=name,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self,email,name,age,username, password):

        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            password=password,
            age=age,
            name=name,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True

        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class UserSignupModel(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60,unique=True)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="date joined", auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="last login", auto_now=True)

    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "username"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email','name','age']
    objects = SignUpManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
#migrate --run-syncdb in case no work
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login,authenticate,logout
from diabetes.forms import UserSignupForm,UserLoginForm



# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request,'diabetes/home.html')

def signupuser(request):
    context={}
    if request.POST:
        form=UserSignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            email=form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            raw_password=form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            name=form.cleaned_data.get('name')
            age=form.cleaned_data.get('age')
            username=form.cleaned_data.get('username')

            account=authenticate(email=email,password=raw_password,name=name,age=age,username=username)
            login(request,account)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            context["reg_form"]=form

    else:
        form = UserSignupForm()
        context["reg_form"] = form
    return render (request,'diabetes/signupuser.html',context)


def logoutuser(request):

    logout(request)
    return redirect('home')

def loginuser(request):
    context={}

    user=request.user
    if user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')


    if request.method=="POST":

        form=UserLoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            email=request.POST['email']
            password=request.POST['password']
            user=authenticate(password=password,email=email,backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')

            if user:
                login(request,user)
                return redirect("home")

    else:
        form=UserLoginForm()


    context['form']=form
    return render(request,"diabetes/loginuser.html",context)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [model with this Email already exists in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61875362/model-with-this-email-already-exists-in-django)

Comment: this was for an intendation issue! new problem is authentication is not working. it gives invalid login while email address in db.